# Use python module as commands in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, python-module

Just like when you install a `pip` module in bash you can use it straight away from the Terminal without needing to start python like a system command.
Is there a way to do the same thing in windows command prompt without it showing the error "command not found"?

Comment: Some packages install scripts, if that's what you mean. There's no common bin directory in Windows, so a package's scripts get installed to Python's "Scripts" subdirectory. Add that directory to `PATH`. The installer for 3.5+ actually has an option to do this for you.

Comment: Like for JavaScript packages can be installed with global flag can be used as a system command in both Windows and Linux command-line interface.
Is there such a way for python modules in windows